# Difference between "had come" vs. "came" vs. "used to come"

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, verb-forms

What is the difference in meaning between these three sentences?

> 1. Aren't they the ones who **had come** over for lunch?
> 2. Aren't they the ones who **came** over for lunch?
> 3. Aren't they the ones who **used to come** over for lunch?

Last one sounds like a habitual and reoccurring action but what do the first and second one mean?

Comment: Please fix your punctuation, and please tell us exactly what you do not understand.

Answer (score 1):

> 1 = **Had Come** Talks about an Action ( in this sentence "come") which has happened before another thing in the past.

Example for Had come : Imagine a situation in which 2 things have happened and we're talking about them :

1 = I did my homework ( at 9 PM)

2 = I watched TV ( at 10 PM)

5 Hours later i want to report these things to my Mother :

Me :Mom, I watched TV at 10 !

Mother : what about your homework ?

Me : I had done my homework before i watched TV.

> 2= **came** Talks about an Action which happened in the past and IS NOW FINISHED. and we're not talking about any other action.
>
> 3 = **used to come** is a different Grammar which talks about an activity that you regularly did in the past and no longer do (it) now.

Example : I used to smoke ( Means : In the past , smoking was a habit of mine and it no longer is)

The Main Source of the answer is **Cambridge Advanced Grammar in Use(Third edition)**

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The first one with the past perfect describes an action that took place earlier than another action in the past. Therefore, we would normally use it to refer to a single incident. If we wanted to refer to something that was recurrent prior to a reference time in the past, we'd use the past perfect continuous.

> Is he the doctor who **had been treating** your bad knee before you
>   moved to Atlanta from New York?

The simple past can be used to refer to individual incidents or recurrent/habitual events.  Absent context, we cannot know which it is.

> Are they the ones who **came** over for lunch that day when I was
>   visiting?
>
> Are they the ones who **came** over for lunch every week after your
>   committee meeting?

Comment: But of course most native USAian speakers would use the simple past in _"Is he the doctor who **was** treating your bad knee before you moved to Atlanta from New York?"_ The past perfect is going the way of the Great Auk, like it or not, a victim of the Great Internet Leveling.

Comment: There has to be some good reason to be referring to the past event in relation to another past. *Is that the same course you were telling me about, the one you had hoped to get into?*

Comment: Of course the past perfect would add clarity to that sentence, but you would almost always hear the sentence spoken as _"Is that the same course you were telling me about, the one you hoped to get into?"_ The Great Auk was a useful bird, too, majestic and colorful. Betamax was a superior format to VHS. &c.